# TASM extra characters when calling subroutine

Tags: assembly, call, subroutine, tasm

So I have this subroutine:

```
proc print_msg msgptr:word
    mov dx, [msgptr]
    mov ah, 9h
    int 21h
    ret
endp
```

I try to call it using

```
call print_msg, offset msg_description
```

but on this line, tasm says "extra characters on line". How to fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`call` only takes a single operand, the address of the subroutine. You need to pass arguments by hand, according to whatever convention `tasm` uses if you declare a `proc` like you did. Assuming it uses the usual stack based convention, you will need something like:

```
push offset msg_description
call print_msg
add sp, 2 ; remove argument if called proc doesn't end with `ret 2`
```